# Styling of Notepad++ end of line (EOL) symbols "CR" and "LF"?

Tags: notepad++, color-theme

I would like to enable `View>Show Symbol>Show all characters` but in contrast to Style `White space symbol`style in Language `Global Styles` I can't find a color setting for the EOL character so I am stuck with what seems to be pure white. I would like to use a color similar to the whitespace setting to better fit with a dark theme (Monokai).

Where is this setting hidden or does it not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a discussion [How to make CR/LF not White on Black](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/2eeb88f4)  so this option is not implemented:

> Well, there is a way to change the color of the CR LF new line
>   characters…
>
> Make them (part of) a comment section.
>
> You may understand from this that the CR LF new line characters always
>   have the same color as the text or (key)word (type) they belong to or
>   that just preceeds them.

Now it looks like this and IMHO can't be changed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The [How to make CR/LF not White on Black](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/2eeb88f4) discussion is now locked. The most relevant link for now [is this github post](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1260#issuecomment-683334493), probably.

Answer (score 1):

They fixed this in a recent version! You can now choose the EOL character colour in the menu "Settings" -> "Style Configurator".

Select "Global Styles" on the left list, scroll down the right list and look for "EOL custom color". Pick you colour, then click "Go to Settings", and tick the "Custom Color" checkbox under "EOL (CRLF)". You can also get rid of the inverted background by choosing "Plain Text".

[image: Screenshot of the preferences dialog showing the EOL color configuration location as described in the answer]